# SQL Server 2008, Convert decimal value to percentage without rounding?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

How can I convert the number 0.967741935483870967742 to %96.77 without rounding values?

So far I have

```
SELECT 
     VAL1 = '%' + convert(varchar, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), 0.967741935483870967742 * 100 )
FROM my_table
```

which gives me %97.00;

Edit:
I tried doing this without any success:

```
SELECT 
     VAL1 = '%' + convert(varchar, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), 0.967741935483870967742 * CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), 100) )
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT '%'+LEFT(CAST((0.96774*100) as VARCHAR),5)
```

Comment: you've got it, it was inside the same cast, next to 0.96774*100

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
SELECT 
'%' + convert(varchar, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), 0.967741935483870967742 * 100 ))
```

Comment: Nope, it gives %970.00.